# How to set textarea width inside some contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

When I try to set textarea as follows. I could set `max-width: 50rem` as follows.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50rem
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">test</div>
    <textarea class="box">test</textarea>
</div>
```

[image]

But when I add `class="template"`, the textarea is shortened as follows. My desired result is to set textarea `max-width:50rem` as above.

But when I set the following class, the width is shortened.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50rem
}

.template {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3rem 1fr;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="template">
    <div class="label">test</div>
    <textarea class="box">test</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I set `max-width:50rem` inside `<div class="template">` ?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `max-width` isn't working because the `row` element makes it to small to take any max-height into effect.

I'd use a `flex-grow: 1;` on the `.template` to let it grow so the `max-width` will trigger

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50rem
}

.template {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3rem 1fr;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="template">
    <div class="label">test</div>
    <textarea class="box">test</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```